# How can I view .swf files within Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, flash, swf

I have been sent a number of .swf files as attachments. I wish to view these within Mac OS X. I used to drag them directly into Safari and it would display them. However, after installing Safari 4 I only get a blank white window content when I do this.

How can I view these files on my Mac for free?

Comment: Similar to @hasseg's answer, I recently got a fresh Mavericks laptop and was able to play .swf files in Chrome 35 from my harddrive with no problem. [playerversion.com](http://playerversion.com) says I have flash version MAC 14.0.0.125.

Comment: FYI, I had the same problem with Safari 8 even with the latest Shockwave Player.  My colleague recommended Opera which worked.  I am guessing folks who it worked for had a setting or something and have forgot, but who knows.  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Drag the swf into Chrome.  It was the flash player in it by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://mac.eltima.com/freeflashplayer.html

Update: That link will take you to the free software I was talking about, but just noticed as of July 2010, the company is changing the software name to elmedia player.

Answer (score 20):

I have *Safari v.4.0.3* and *Flash Player plugin v.10,0,12,36 (Debug player)* installed in *Mac OS 10.5.8* and opening `.swf` files in the browser works just fine for me. I don't know if it has anything to do with the fact that I have the *debug* version of Flash Player, but I suspect it'll work with the standard version as well, like it always has before Safari 4. So [try updating your Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and see if it'll work after that.

If you'd like to open `.swf` files outside of your browser, you can install Adobe's [*standalone ("projector") Flash Player*](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

p.s. You can check the version of your Flash Player plugin by going to http://playerversion.com

Comment: Using the browser or Adobe's own standalone player is really a much safer and no-hassle way to approach this problem. I think this answer deserves to be marked as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iSwiff](http://echoone.com/iswiff/). It is a standalone SWF player for Mac.

Comment: This was free and worked. Not extensively tested, but seems legit and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Just Get Perian. It's free and can play just about anything. It has almost every Codex available. Just install and go.

http://perian.org/

Comment: This project has been nuked